# My array.sort that I'm using in netbeans, isn't sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm quite new to Java and recently I wanted to practice more. So I stumbled in this. I wanted to print out all the values in the array using Array.sort, but all I get is:`1,2,3,4,5,6` instead of;`22,51,67,12,98,34`.
Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] array;

            array =new int[6];
            array[0]=22;
            array[1]=51;
            array[2]=67;
            array[3]=12;
            array[4]=98;
            array[5]=34;

          Arrays.sort(array);

       int i;

       for (i=0; i < array.length; i++){
              array[i]= i+1;
            System.out.println("num is"+array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Just commenting to let you know, this is not related to netbeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're refilling the elements in `array[i]` inside the `for` loop. Just print the contents of the array:

```
for (i=0; i < array.length; i++){
    //remove this line since it's setting the value of (i+1) to array[i]
    //array[i]= i+1;
    //leave this line only
    System.out.println("num is"+array[i]);
}
```

Or, use `Arrays.toString` to display the content of your array:

```
//no for loop needed
System.out.println("Array data: " + Arrays.toString(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use your own code, EG:

```
private void butgoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    int nums[] = {13,6, 1, 25,18,12};                
    //Array is called "nums", holds random numbers and such

    int place = 0;
    int check = 0;

    while (place < nums.length - 1) {

        while (check < nums.length) {             
            // "Check" loops inside place and checks to see where larger

            if (nums[place] > nums[check]) {     
                //Change To < For Descending

                int temp = nums[place];
                nums[place] = nums[check];      
                //"Check" swaps the values around

                nums[check] = temp;

            }
            check++;

        }

        //"Place" tells loop when to stop and holds a value to be compared

        place++;
        check = place + 1;
    }

    place = 0;                              
    //"Place" acts as a counter

    while (place < nums.length) {     
        //Output Loop
        txtout.append("\n" + nums[place] + "");     
        //"txtoutput" is the textarea (.append means to add to the text already there

        place++;                             
        //"\n" means new line
    }


}
```

Comment: This... Doesn't really answer the question.